# Erro ao usar o comando find com mongoose (Converting circular structure to JSON)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou executando consultas no mongodb com o mongoose , se eu uso a findOne ele retorna um objeto certinho, porém se eu uso o find({}) para listar todos os campos esta dando erro.

Segue meu código:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.get = async (req, res) => {

    const mongoDB = 'mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/teste';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', (erro) => {
        console.log('Mongoose! Erro na conexao em ' + erro);
    });

    db.on('connected', () => {
        console.log('Mongoose! Conectado em ' + mongoDB);
    });

    db.on('disconected', () => {
        console.log('Mongoose! Desconectado em ' + mongoDB);
    });


    try {

        const docs = await db.collection('nfce').find({
            num_loj: 1
        });

        console.log(docs);

        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            results: docs.length,
            data: {
                docs
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            err: error,
        });
    }
}
```

Segue erro:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at exports.get (C:\server\src\controllers\notasFiscaisController.js:34:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Versões:

> "nodejs":" 14.18.1" "mongoose": "5.13.12" "mongodb": "4.1.3"

Exemplo de um retorno da collection :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6182d5a173f464354b5b4d7e"
    },
    "num_loj": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "num_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "999999"
    },
    "sre_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "8"
    },
    "seq": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "ope": {
        "$numberLong": "102"
    },
    "num_pdv": {
        "$numberLong": "8"
    },
    "tip_ems": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "num_lot": {
        "$numberLong": "999999"
    },
    "dat_hor_ems": {
        "$date": "2021-10-01T10:06:29.000Z"
    },
    "dat_hor_rcb": {
        "$date": "2021-10-01T10:06:30.000Z"
    },
    "chv_acs": "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999",
    "dgt_vlr": "jsdfhdsjfhdsjfhsdjfhdsjfhdj=",
    "num_ptc": {
        "$numberLong": "999999999999999"
    },
    "num_rcb": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "amb": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "cod_sfz": {
        "$numberLong": "100"
    },
    "msg_sfz": "Autorizado o uso da NF-e",
    "mtv_sfz": "Autorizado o uso da NF-e",
    "xml_env": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><enviNFe xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\" versao=\"4.00\"><idLote></NFe></enviNFe>",
    "xml_ret": "<retEnviNFe xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\" xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\" </retEnviNFe>",
    "sit_env_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "2"
    },
    "mtv_ctg": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "dat_hor_ult_env": {
        "$date": "2021-10-01T10:06:32.000Z"
    },
    "qtd_env_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "cod_ret_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "cod_err_nfc": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "msg_err_nfc": "SUCESSO",
    "qrcode": "https://nfce.faz........",
    "vrs_lay_nfc": 4
}
```

Comment: Tentou passar o `.toArray()`? ex: `await db.collection('nfce').find({ num_loj: 1 }).toArray()`

Comment: Existe algum documento na collection que está com algum atributo "circular".
Terá o trabalho de descobrir qual documento é para ajustar. Experimentou utilizar o ".toArray()" conforme sugestão do Cardeal?

Comment: @CmteCardeal da erro : TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).toArray is not a function

Comment: @FelipePellegrini sim, esta dando erro: TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).toArray is not a function , quando você diz  ( algum atributo "circular" ) me da um exemplo por favor

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa podes mostrar a collection que esta a tentar buscar, isso certamente pode ajudar a compreender melhor o erro.

Comment: @CristianoGilbertoJoão adicionei um exemplo de retorno na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode usar este código onde `catch` tenta colocar o objeto de erro diretamente como `json`. O objeto de erro contém um loop em sua própria estrutura e, portanto, não pode ser usado diretamente.

não:

```
res.status(404).json({
  status: 'fail',
  err: error,
});
```

sim:
(dois casos)

```
if(err.name === 'ValidationError') 
   return err = handleValidationError(err, res);
if(err.code && err.code == 11000) 
   return err = handleDuplicateKeyError(err, res); 

// duplicados
const handleDuplicateKeyError = (err, res) => {
   const field = Object.keys(err.keyValue);   
   const code = 409;
   const error = `${field} é duplicado.`;
   res.status(code).send({messages: error, fields: field});
}

// validacão:
const handleValidationError = (err, res) => {   
   let errors = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.message);
   let fields = Object.values(err.errors).map(el => el.path);
   let code = 400;
   if(errors.length > 1) {
     const formattedErrors = errors.join(' ');
     res.status(code).send({messages: formattedErrors, fields: fields});
   } else {
      res.status(code).send({messages: errors, fields: fields})
   }
}
```

Mais em ingles:

[1] https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-errors-in-mongoose-express-for-display-in-react-d966287f573b